# Resize a LVM partition on linux disk of Azure

Tags: disk-usage

I have created a Vm in Azure with Oracle Linux 9. I have selected a 128G disk but when I see the size of the partitions I see that it was not fully used.

```
[root@oraclelinux ~]$ lsblk
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda                  8:0    0  128G  0 disk
├─sda1               8:1    0  800M  0 part /boot
├─sda2               8:2    0 28.7G  0 part
│ ├─rootvg-rootlv  252:0    0 18.7G  0 lvm  /
│ └─rootvg-crashlv 252:1    0   10G  0 lvm  /var/crash
├─sda14              8:14   0    4M  0 part
└─sda15              8:15   0  495M  0 part /boot/efi
sdb                  8:16   0   32G  0 disk
└─sdb1               8:17   0   32G  0 part /mnt
```

I need to add all extra space available to the rootvg-rootlv partition. I haven't found in the Azure documentation a way. How is it possible to add more space to the partition with mount point / ?

```
[root@oraclelinux ~]$ parted /dev/sda print
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use 
all of the space (an extra 205520896 blocks) or continue with the current setting?
Fix/Ignore? ignore

Model: Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 137GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
14      1049kB  5243kB  4194kB                                     bios_grub
15      5243kB  524MB   519MB   fat16        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 1      525MB   1364MB  839MB   xfs
 2      1364MB  32.2GB  30.8GB                                     lvm
```

Comment: Sorry about picture, I've changed to text and ran the parted `parted /dev/sda print` command. Note that a waring message say "Not all space is used..." I 've selected "ignore fix" while wait for  you intructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off:

1. If this is a production system then do not make any changes without first testing elsewhere
2. Take a backup (or external snapshot) before making any changes

The `parted` output shows the partitions in order across the disk. Fortunately the LVM partition is at the end of the list and so it can be trivially extended.

All the following should be run as root. (Have you taken a backup yet?)

1. Allow `parted` to fix the discrepancy between actual disk size and reported disk size. You may need to schedule a reboot before continuing
2. Resize the LVM partition to take the remainder of the disk:

   ```
   parted /dev/sda resizepart 2 100%
   ```
3. Resize the Physical Volume container that's inside the resized partition:

   ```
   pvresize /dev/sda2
   ```

   You should now have a VG that is large enough to allow your Logical Volumes to be grown. Check that the `VSize` is now approaching your 126GB rather than just 30GB:

   ```
   vgs
   ```
4. Resize the Logical Volume for the root filesystem, also increasing the size of the filesystem it holds:

   ```
   lvextend --size +50GB --resizefs /dev/rootvg/rootlv
   ```

   Here I've extended the filesystem by 50GB rather than the entire amount, so that there's spare available to extend or create another filesystem in the same VG. If you can pretty much guarantee this won't be necessary you can extend the `rootlv` to use the full amount of space